# what the meaning of (a&b)>>c in this systemc code?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and, systemc

when I read SYSTEMC code,I find a function return int like this:

```
static inline int rp_get_busaccess_response(struct rp_pkt *pkt)
{
    return (pkt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes & RP_BUS_RESP_MASK) >>
                                                            RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT;
}
```

`pkt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes` defined as `uint64_t`.

`RP_BUS_RESP_MASK` and `RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT` defined as:

```
enum {
    RP_RESP_OK                  =  0x0,
    RP_RESP_BUS_GENERIC_ERROR   =  0x1,
    RP_RESP_ADDR_ERROR          =  0x2,
    RP_RESP_MAX                 =  0xF,
};
```

```
enum {
    RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT    =  8,
    RP_BUS_RESP_MASK     =  (RP_RESP_MAX << RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT),
};
```

What the meaning of this function's return?

Thanks!

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND operator, and `>>` is right shift operator. Next step, use a pen and paper to calculate.

Comment: It's a bitmask operation followed by a bitshift operation.

Comment: It extracts a number of bits (4) from `pkt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes` and shift them down to start at bit position zero. Seems it extracts bit[11:8]

Comment: This is a very generic way of working with hardware registers. Normally these are squashed with multiple values of various things into a single register. Here, in your case, you obtain some kind of bus response status. To obtain the status value you mask the register to leave only bits of the actual status, and then shift it to make the value usable in your program logic.

Comment: [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/995714)

Comment: @SupportUkraine *It extracts a number of bits (4)...*  But be careful with `enum` bit values.  If the `enum` is signed (implementation-defined) and the input value is negative, [the results of a right shift are implementation-defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5).  Using `enum` for bit values that will be shifted can be dangerous if care is not taken.  You might get more bits set than you thought you would - or even could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a & b` is a bitwise operation, this will perform a logical `AND` to each pair of bits, let's say you have `262 & 261` this will translate to `100000110 & 100000101` the result will be `100000100` (`260`), the logic behind the result is that each `1 AND 1` will result in `1` whereas `1 AND 0` and `0 AND 0` will result in `0`, these are normal logical operations but are performed at bit level:

```
  100000110
& 100000101
-----------
  100000100
```

In `(a & b) >> c`, `>>` will shift the bits of the resulting value of `a & b` to the right by `c` positions. For example for the previous result `100000100` and having a `c` value of `8`, all bits will shift to the right by `8`, and the result is `000000001`. The left most `1` bit in the original value will become the first most right whereas the third `1` bit from the right in the original value will be *shifted away*.

With this knowledge in mind and looking at the function, we can see that the `RP_BUS_RESP_MASK` constant is a mask that *protects* the field of bits from 9th through 12th position(from the right, *i.e.* the first four bits of the second byte), setting them to `1` (`RP_RESP_MAX << RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT` which translates to `1111` << `8` resulting in `111100000000`), this will preserve the bit values in that range. Then it sets the other bits of `pkt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes` to `0` when it performs the bitwise `&` against this mask. Finally it shifts this field to the right by `RP_BUS_RESP_SHIFT`(`8`).

It basically extracts the the first four bits in the second byte of `kt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes` and returns the result as an integer.

What it's for specifically? You must consult the documentation if it exists or try to understand its use in the global context, for what I can see this belongs to [LibSystemCTLM-SoC](https://github.com/Xilinx/libsystemctlm-soc)  (In case you didn't know)

Answer (score 2):

The function extracts the first 4-Bit of the second byte of the 8-Byte (64-Bit) Attribute. This means, it extracts the following 4-Bits of the Attribute 0xFFFF FFFF FFFFF F**A**FF resulting in 0x0**A**

- First it creates the mask, which is `RP_BUS_RESP_MASK = 0x0F00`
- Next it applies the mask to the attribute `pkt->busaccess_ext_base.attributes & 0x0F00` resulting in 0x0A00 from the example
- Next it shifts **A** by 8-Bit to the right side, leading to 0x0A

Comment: Shift is 8 bits, not 16: `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FAFF`

Comment: thats of curse correct, I changed the initial post.

Comment: Next it shifts A by 8-Bit to the **right** side. Sorry for nitpicking :D Will give you +1 once fixed.

Comment: ah, damn, I was thinking it to the **right** direction.